# How to insert md5 hash value in MS sql server?

Tags: php, sql-server, encryption, md5

I have table user which have password field. Here I want to input md5 hash value directly from database since my haven't prepare for registration apps. Is there any function or attributes for column. I search for that option and couldn't found any options in sql server database and I am using md5 function in php to select password of user table

Comment: You probably [shouldn't use MD5](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Cryptography#Hashes) to protect your passwords.

Comment: On a picky note: you're talking about hashing, not encryption.  Also, what is your question asking? You're trying to automatically hash on insertion without having to change code?  Just update them once in the database, then change the code.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't provide the MD5 or SHA1 functions you may be expecting from MySQL, if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Does this mean your passwords in your database aren't hashed at all?

I know this isn't the answer you are looking for but:

1. MD5 is the wrong hash to use for passwords. It is too quick. You need to use a [hashing algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) that takes a lot more time.
2. [Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29).

Or better yet, use a proven library to handle it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Use HASHBYTES: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx

```
SELECT
    HashBytes('MD5', '123456') AS md5hash
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case I did that way :

```
 Select Lower(CONVERT(VARCHAR(32),HashBytes('MD5', '12345'), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php 
 $encryptedstring = mdecrypt_generic($yourdata)
 $encryptedstring // insert this value in database
 ?>
```

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a little script in php, with update query.

```
   select users.....;
         for loop
             md5 pass + update users
         end for
```